# Regular expression match if there's non-alphabetical character at the end, or nothing?

Tags: regex, perl, cpu-word

I have some regular expressions that match homonyms, like `tw?oo?` would match either `two`, `to`, or `too`. (It also matches `twoo`, but that's ok).

My question is, I want the regular expression to match if there is punctuation or some other nonalphabetical character at the ends, like `to,` or `two.` or even `,too!`. If there's nothing at the end, that's ok as well.

So I want it to match `tw?oo?` if there are no other characters on each side, **or** if there are non-alphabetical characters, but **not** if there are letters around: `tomorrow` shouldn't match.

I tried `[^A-Za-z]?tw?oo?[^A-Za-z]?` , but since the character classes are optional they just get ommitted.

How would I do this, so the regex only matches the words if they are on their own, or surrounded by punctutation. (spaces aren't a problem, they've been cut out)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries `\b`. They match whenever a word character (`\w`) and a non-word character are adjacent:

```
for (qw/two to tomorrow/) {
  say "$_ ", /\b(?:two|to|too)\b/ ? "matches" : "doesn't match";
}
```

Output:

```
two matches
to matches
tomorrow doesn't match
```

#### Edit

I changed the regex to `/\b(?:two|to|too)\b/` per tobyink's suggestion. This is more readable than `tw?oo?` and more correct than `tw?o+`, and triggers the *trie optimization*, which transforms that part of the regex into a very efficient state machine.

Comment: `\btw?o+\b` also matches `tooooooo`, it might be better to change it to `\btw?oo?\b`

Comment: Or even `\b(to|too|two)\b`